# Can I install UEFI Windows 8 through a DVD or must it be a USB?

Tags: uefi

I've read a few articles that all say to install Windows 8 through USB to achieve UEFI. I have my laptop turned onto UEFI mode but when I switch from legacy to UEFI it doesn't recognize any options to boot from. I in the same Dell bios there is an option to enable USB boot support, so now I'm just confused as to what I should use. Any tips? I have a dvd and it's not working, as in the computer starts and doesn't recognize it but if I switch to legacy then it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the DVD option doesn't work, you could always try the USB option. Simply select all the files in the DVD and copy and paste it over to the USB drive and boot from the USB drive. UEFI does not need a specific boot sector, hence simply copying will work.

Additional note:
UEFI relies on a specific directory structure e.g. boot\UEFI..

Comment: Thanks, I put copied the files from the DVD I created from the Win 8 Pro .iso and I sent them to my removable drive. UEFI recognized it, and now I'm booting from UEFI. Awesome!

Answer (score 3):

UEFI mode only recognizes a bootable USB drive that meets the following requirements:

- Format as FAT32. It doesn't recognize NTFS devices.
- Use the GPT (GUID Partition Table) partition scheme.
- A 64-bit UEFI capable operating system installed on your USB drive.